# Get form input value from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm using Angularjs to submit the form then pass the value to my laravel function.

This is my HTML code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name='form' novalidate ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="syncApiCtrl">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your_name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         <input type="submit" name="sale" value="Sync Sale" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
         <input type="submit" novalidate ng-click="sync_product(record)" name="product" value="Sync Product" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is my JS

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    //$scope.form.$submitted = true;
    // proceed if form valid
    if ($scope.form.$valid) {
        // is loading
        $scope.loading = true;
        // prepare data packet
        var data = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.form, function (v, k) {
            if (k.indexOf('$') < 0 && typeof v.$dirty !== 'undefined' && v.$dirty) {
                data[k] = v.$modelValue;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This is my laravel function

```
public function sync_sale() {   
    $name= preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\_]/', '', Input::get('name'));
    Debugbar::info($name);
}
```

My laravel function always can't get the value after user submit a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have bound your input to a ng-model. This one is working. You should use data binding methods in angularJs.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your_name" ng-model="name">
```